# React Native - do not stop on page,

Tags: react-native, parameter-passing, react-native-router-flux

I'm new to React Native. I'm trying to send parameters between pages through 'Actions' from react-native-router-flux. 'Actions' is called on 'onPress' method of 'TouchableOpacity'. But the things is that, when I do not give any parameter to 'Actions' it works properly, without any problem. But when I give some parameter, it does not wait on the page, immediately redirects to the new page just like 'TouchableOpacity' is clicked.

Here are both codes with parameter and without parameter.

[image] without parameter

[image: .e]

with parameter, do not work properly,don't wait for press, immediatetly navigate when page is rendered

Comment: You are better to put code itself, instead of it's picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exectuing a function instead of giving `onPress` a function.

Your first example works because you did not call the function. Calling it with no parameters would be `Actions.home()`, but you wrote `Actions.home` which returns the `home` function.

Your code should be `onPress={() => Actions.home(data.id)}` which is simply creating a function for `onPress`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot and also made me understand better, how React-Native works.